# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I am new to iOS. I am making an app in which i am getting response from json all are working fine. i am storing response in an array but when i am setting the array  value to tableview cell like this

```
valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"]
```

it is giving an exception what i am mistaking.Thanx in advance. below is my sample code.

```
-(void)viewdidload{
  NSMutableDictionary *callDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [callDict setObject:@"messages-getModuleMessages" forKey:@"call"];
    [callDict setObject:FB_API_KEY forKey:@"accessSecret"];
    NSString *x=[FBUserManager sharedUserManager].authToken;
    [callDict setObject:x forKey:@"authToken"];
    [callDict setObject:@"json" forKey:@"format"];
    [callDict setObject:@"inbox" forKey:@"callType"];

    FBGenericWebHandler *handler = [[FBGenericWebHandler alloc] init];
    handler.delegate = self;
    [handler Inboxmessages:callDict];
    handler = nil;
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];



}
```

and i am getting response like this

```
-(void)inboxmessagesGetSuccess:(FBGenericWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSMutableArray *inboxArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSArray *firstarray=[[[response objectForKey:@"messageResponse"] objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"messages"];
    for(NSDictionary *tmp in firstarray)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *messages=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [messages setValue:[tmp objectForKey:@"messageId"] forKey:@"messageId"];
        [self.inboxmessagesarray addObject:messages];




    }
    [self.activitiesTableView_ reloadData];


}
```

and setting my cell like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
    tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){
        // [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Load more records"];
    }

    UILabel *valuedate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:21];
    UILabel *msg = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:22];
    UILabel *date = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:23];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:24];
   valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is your `numberOfRowsInSection:` method?

Comment: Also, is your cell defined as a prototype cell in a storyboard?  If so you can skip the whole `if (cell==nil...` bit.  Also, I would suggest creating a UITableViewCell subclass and using `IBOutlet` properties rather than searching for views with tag. Finally, it is cleaner to use the `tableView` that was passed to the method rather than using `self.activitiesTableView_` (and ditch the trailing _ from the property)

Answer (score 2):

Its straightforward as the error says "'NSRangeException', reason: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'", your array is empty and you are trying to access its 0th (i.e. first element).

What you can do is do a check before retrieving the value as : `if ([yourArray count] > 0){....}`

```
if (self.inboxmessagesarray.count > 0){
    valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"]
}
```

Comment: hmm but how can i get this array in view did load as array conatins 20 objects

Comment: hmm but inbox message array is coming nil in uitable view but in response i am getting objects.. but these objects are not coming in uitable method why ?

Comment: That is to be expected if your load is completing asynchronously.  That is why I asked what your `numberOfRowsInSection` is - the array can be nil as long as that method returns 0 when it is

Comment: i am defining return 20 in number of rows in section

Answer (score 1):

You probably have self.inboxmessagesarray.count+1 (Plus 1 for load more)  innumberOfRowsInSection: method and when self.inboxmessagesarray.count == 0 Then you are     `valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"];`
Which throws this exception

Comment: then how it would handle

Comment: if (self.inboxmessagesarray.count > 0){
    valuedate.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageId"]
}